# to print words seperated with special charecters in shell script

Tags: shell

shell script to print three words differently I have tried

```
{ 
a="Uname/pass@last"
echo $a | tr "/" "\n" | tr "@" "\n"
output is:
Uname
pass
last
}
```

I want it as

```
{Username- Uname
Password- pass
lastname-last}
```

Comment: I want the results in different lines

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess you want to add a prefix to each results:

```
printf 'Username\nPassword\nlastname' > /tmp/prefixes

a="Uname/pass@last"
echo "${a}" | tr '/@' '\n\n' | paste -d':' /tmp/prefixes -
```

ie: paste together the output of `/tmp/prefixes` and of the Standard Input (`-`), which is receiving the output of : `echo ".../...@..." | tr '/@' '\n\n'`
  (and in the resulting output, separate the 2 with a `:` in this example, or whatever else you would want. Ex: `-` like in your question.)

and it outputs :

```
Username:user
Password:pass
lastname:last
```

(I know you wanted a `-` instead of a `:` but I give my example with `:` to better separate the "-" denoting the standard input, and the ":" denoting the field-separator character in the output. Just change `-d':'` into `-d'-'` to have  a `-` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I hope you're not going to manipulate important passwords in a shell script and external commands. There are some risks involved with that.

---

### Defining the problem

I suspect you want split a string encoding a user's Username, password and surname into a three line structure, adding tags to document which is which. For that, `tr` is insufficient.

However, it can be done inside the shell.

### Example (bash, ksh):

```
function split_account_string {
  typeset account=${1:?account string} uname pass last t

  uname=${account%%/*}
  last=${account##*@}
  t=${account#$uname/}
  pass=${t%@*}

  [[ $uname/$pass@$last == "$account" ]] || return

  echo "{Username-$uname"
  echo "Password-$pass"
  echo "lastname-$last}"
}

split_account_string "USER_A/seKreT@John.Doe"
```

This function will extract all tokens between the *first* `/` and the *last* `@` as the value of the password.  If either one is missing, it will print nothing, and return an error status.

When run, this gives:

```
{Username-USER_A
Password-seKreT
lastname-John.Doe}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple script and get the output.

```
#!/bin/bash
a="Uname/pass@last"
array2=(`echo $a | tr "/" "\n" | tr "@" "\n"`)
array1=(`echo -e "Username\nPassword\nlastname"`)
i=${#array1[@]}
for (( j=0 ; j<$i ; j++ ))
do
   echo "${array1[$j]}=${array2[$j]}"
done
```